# how to register to consul in Kubernetes by using Cluster IP instead of POD IP at Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway Hoxton.SR5 version. My service is registered to Consul with POD ID instead of service or cluster ID. That's fine but I would rather to register my service to consul service or cluster ID instead of POD IP address. Do you think change should be done from application.yml or spring cloud gateway has configuration for that ? 
While making or tests in Kubernetes dev environment, we saw that services registered to consul with their pod IP addresses instead of the service IP address. This make problem under high traffic since Kubernetes have rolling strategy to de-register pod. E.g: Pod A will be removed and Pod B will be started. Pod A remains in the cluster (maybe just 3-4 seconds) until Pod B is live, but this 3-4 seconds time consul may try to forward a request to Pod A, but it will be removed soon. Instead, if consul uses service IP which does not change on the port restart, then problem is fixed.
Thanks

```
 consul:
    host: localhost
    port: 8450
    discovery:
       preferIpAddress :true
```

Comment: If you do that, what does it register with consul with?

Comment: additional services will be registered to consul.In Kubernetes if one pod dies then another pod takes places instead of it but when I use pod IP address a problem raises. Instead of that during the registration process of a service, I would like to use the service address instead of the pod Address. The solution above solves it or do you have any additional suggestion ?

Comment: I don't know. I've never run consul on kubernetes. Hence, my question, have you tried it and what happens?

Comment: I did but the solution did not come out .

Comment: What did happen? Then you need to set `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.hostname` explicitly.

Comment: it still saw the pod address instead of the service address. ok I will try it with spring.cloud.discovery.hostname explicitly

Comment: hello @spencergibb that solution does not work as well. I want to see the Cluster IP instead of the POD IP. my application         ClusterIP   10.103.53.241    <none>        8080/TCP   52d
 Unfortunately in the consul I can only see the PODIP which changes when I restart the application

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: I think you've had a good conversation on gitter